# Is it possible to Recognize the Character drawn on iPhone screen using Tesseract OCR?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ocr

From the past 2 weeks i am trying to implement "Recognize the character drawn on iPhone screen".
 i Search for this and i found Tesseract OCR.

By using Tesseract OCR we are able to recognize characters from a picture.
 Now my question is Is it possible to recognize the character drawn on iPhone screen using Tesseract OCR?

if it Possible give me some initial steps to achieve this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Computer Vision is all about training. You need to create several hundred (maybe thousand) sample shots of what you might be trying to parse in order to train Tesseract to detect it. Once you think you have it trained enough, train more with new images. Then again withe even newer images. The more sample data the better. Once you have a trained AI, taking a screenshot of the users input is trivial, then pass it to Tesseract to parse. Be sure to include a "Help us train with this image" feature in your app in case you get it wrong, so you can train on real-time data from users.